# In Codename One, generic method to get all Components of a given type

Tags: codenameone

I know that in Codename One I can get all Components of a given type (and its subtypes) using a recursive method like the following:

```
recursiveSearch(Display.getInstance().getCurrent());

public void recursiveSearch(Container cnt) {
    for (Component cmp : cnt.getChildrenAsList(true)) {
        if (cmp instanceof Label) {
            // for debugging
            Log.p(cmp.toString());
        } else if (cmp instanceof Container) {
            recursiveSearch((Container) cmp);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to generalize this type of search, because I use it a lot of times during the development.

That's why I wrote a new class with two static methods for this purpose. But my code is not an exact equivalent of the previous `recursiveSearch`, because it doesn't return subtypes. For example, if I'm looking for all the `Label`s, I expect to get also `Button`s, because a `Button` is a `Label`. But this is not the case: with the following code, I'll get only the instances of `Label` that are not instances of subclasses of `Label`.

Can you help me to fix it? Thank you

I understand that this question is referring more to generic Java than to
Codename One, however its use is specific for Codename One.

```
public class Selector extends ComponentSelector {

    /**
     * Returns a Set of Components of the given type.
     *
     * @param <T>
     * @param type
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Component> Set<T> $(Class<T> type) {
        return Selector.$(type, null);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a Set of Components of the given type, searching for them in the
     * children of the given Container.
     *
     * @param <T>
     * @param type
     * @param root
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Component> Set<T> $(Class<T> type, Container root) {
        Set<T> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        if (root == null) {
            root = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
            if (root == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Selector.$(Class<T> type) invoked without a shown Form");
            }
        }
        for (Component cmp : root.getChildrenAsList(true)) {
            if (cmp.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                result.add((T) cmp);
            } else if (cmp instanceof Container) {
                result.addAll(Selector.$(type, (Container) cmp));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

An example of testing:

```
Log.p(Selector.$(Label.class).toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you turn this:

```
cmp.getClass().isAssignableFrom(type)
```

To this:

```
type.isAssignableFrom(cmp.getClass())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the wrapper function that I use to do this very thing.

```
    /**
     * Find set of specific type of component in subtree rooted at root container.
     * @param <T> The type of the component to find.
     * @param type The class of the component to find.
     * @param root The root from which to search
     * @return A set of components of the given type.
     */
    public static <T> Set<T> select(Class<T> type, Container root) {
        return (Set<T>) $("*", root).filter(c -> {
            return type.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass());
        });
    }
```

Notice, the `filter()` method of ComponentSelector almost does everything already.  Wrapping it with a method that has a type parameter just makes it more convenient to use.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification, I thought this feature was missing. What about the performance? Is the ComponentSelector implementation working in a recursive way like my code, or it uses a different approach? If the performance is equivalent, the only difference is that the code I posted can be adapted to get any object, not only Components (changing <T extends Component>). For example, I'll probably need to get all Images with a given name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm wrong: I cannot get all Images or anything that is not a Component because I use `root.getChildrenAsList(true)` that returns only Components.

Comment: ComponentSelector works recursively when the selector string calls for it.  E.g. `"*"` says, "Select All components in the hierarchy rooted at "root".    But you could also tell it to select only direct children, using `">*"`.  Or only grand children:  `">*>*"`.  Or children AND grand children only.  `">*, >*>*"`.